# Pruning directories from a find command and appending with a `/`

Tags: bash, shell

I am using the following command to find all files and directories excluding symlinks and appending a trailing `/` at the end of directories only:

`find $METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -type l '(' '(' -type d -printf '%p/\n' ')' -o -print ')'`

I want to exclude one of the directories and so I did:

`find $METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -type l '(' '(' -type d '(' -path $METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump ')' -prune -o -printf '%p/\n' ')' -o -print ')'`

This does exclude the db2dump directory from the output but also appends a `/` at the end of files. Earlier only directories were getting appended with a `/`. What is wrong with the syntax please?

Comment: Keep in mind that the default way two `find` operators are combined is `-a`, with short-circuiting behavior other languages might write with `&&`. Thus, `-type d -path ... -prune` is pruning if *both* `-type d` and `-path ...` are true, and anything that runs if either of them is false will run just as much if the `-type d` is untrue as it will if the `-prune` is untrue.

Comment: (BTW, the parens surrounding the `-path` have no effect whatsoever -- you group one action together with itself, and it's still... well, *itself*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do we make it work?

Do the prune before you enter either side of your "or" to make it apply to both, and put no other filters (other than the global configuration `-mindepth` and `maxdepth`) before it:

---

```
find "$METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  -path "$METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump" -prune -o \
  '(' ! -type l '(' -type d -printf '%p/\n' ')' -o -print ')'
```

Here, we apply the `-prune` before we enter *either side* of the conditional for which you have the `-printf '%p/'` on the left and the `-print` on the right.

---

#### But why did the original fail?

Frankly, the logical nesting of the original code was a touch hard to follow. To try to make some sense of it, I ended up building a version with proper indentation:

```
find $METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  ! -type l '(' \
                '(' \
                    -type d \
                    '(' \
                       -path $METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump \
                    ')' \
                    -prune \
                    -o -printf '%p/\n' \
                ')' \
                -o -print \
            ')'
```

See how your `-type d` is before the `-path` fed into the `-prune`? You're making *both* the `-type d` and the `-path` part of the left-hand side of an "or" for which the right-hand side is `-printf '%p/\n'`. Thus, whenever `-type d` is false, you fall through the `-or` and reach the `-printf`.